# Jackson returning unwanted numbers in JSON response

Tags: json, hibernate, jackson

I'm seeing a strange issue in my JSON responses where I'm retrieving a collection from a resource, given the resource's ID: Numbers (possibly list indices?) are showing up before or after the JSON object.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "dateCreated": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            9,
            33,
            23000000
        ],
        "dateModified": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            9,
            33,
            23000000
        ],
        "name": "First Check-In",
        "description": null,
        "qualifyingPeriodStartDate": [
            2015,
            9,
            1,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "customers": [],
        "campaign": {
            "id": 1,
            "dateCreated": [
                2015,
                9,
                24,
                14,
                59,
                31,
                474000000
            ],
            "dateModified": [
                2015,
                9,
                24,
                14,
                59,
                31,
                474000000
            ],
            "name": "Background campaign",
            "startDate": [
                2015,
                9,
                1,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "endDate": [
                2016,
                9,
                1,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "chain": null,
            "surveys": [],
            "achievements": [
                1,
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "dateCreated": [
                        2015,
                        9,
                        23,
                        18,
                        10,
                        21,
                        341000000
                    ],
                    "dateModified": [
                        2015,
                        9,
                        23,
                        18,
                        10,
                        21,
                        341000000
                    ],
                    "name": "First Survey Completion",
                    "description": null,
                    "qualifyingPeriodStartDate": [
                        2015,
                        9,
                        1,
                        0,
                        0
                    ],
                    "customers": [],
                    "campaign": 1,
                    "reward": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "dateCreated": [
                            2015,
                            9,
                            24,
                            14,
                            59,
                            31,
                            815000000
                        ],
                        "dateModified": [
                            2015,
                            9,
                            24,
                            14,
                            59,
                            31,
                            815000000
                        ],
                        "name": "McFlurry",
                        "customer": null,
                        "rewardPointValue": 0,
                        "chain": null,
                        "achievements": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "dateCreated": [
                                    2015,
                                    9,
                                    23,
                                    18,
                                    10,
                                    29,
                                    691000000
                                ],
                                "dateModified": [
                                    2015,
                                    9,
                                    23,
                                    18,
                                    10,
                                    29,
                                    691000000
                                ],
                                "name": "First Three Check-Ins",
                                "description": null,
                                "qualifyingPeriodStartDate": [
                                    2015,
                                    9,
                                    8,
                                    0,
                                    0
                                ],
                                "customers": [],
                                "campaign": {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "dateCreated": [
                                        2015,
                                        9,
                                        24,
                                        14,
                                        59,
                                        31,
                                        782000000
                                    ],
                                    "dateModified": [
                                        2015,
                                        9,
                                        24,
                                        14,
                                        59,
                                        31,
                                        782000000
                                    ],
                                    "name": "September campaign",
                                    "startDate": [
                                        2015,
                                        9,
                                        11,
                                        0,
                                        0
                                    ],
                                    "endDate": [
                                        2015,
                                        9,
                                        18,
                                        0,
                                        0
                                    ],
                                    "chain": null,
                                    "surveys": [],
                                    "achievements": [
                                        3
                                    ],
                                    "locations": []
                                },
                                "reward": 1,
                                "numActionsRequired": 3,
                                "actionType": "check-in",
                                "customerActions": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "numActionsRequired": 1,
                    "actionType": "survey-completion",
                    "customerActions": []
                }
            ],
            "locations": []
        },
        "reward": 1,
        "numActionsRequired": 1,
        "actionType": "check-in",
        "customerActions": []
    },
    2
]
```

Can anyone provide some insight into why this is happening, and how to get rid of these numbers? For what it's worth, I'm using Spring with Hibernate and the jackson-datatype-hibernate module. (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)

I'm also using the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation instead of @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

### EDIT 1

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@NamedQuery(name = "Campaign.byId", query = "from Campaign where id=:id")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Campaign.class)
public class Campaign extends NamedEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1781401593603214034L;
    private LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    private LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chain_id")
    private Chain chain;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "campaigns", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Survey> surveys = new ArrayList<Survey>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Achievement> achievements = new ArrayList<Achievement>();
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "campaigns", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private boolean runsIndefinitely;
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Achievement.byId", query = "from Achievement where id=:id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "EligibleAchievements.byCustomerActionId", query = "from Achievement a where :customerActionId not in (select ca.id from a.customerActions as ca) and :customerId not in (select c.id from a.customers as c)"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "CountedAchievements.byCustomerActionId", query = "from Achievement a where :id in (select ca.id from a.customerActions as ca)") })
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Achievement.class)
public class Achievement extends NamedEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8317978091374706947L;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime qualifyingPeriodStartDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_achievements", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "achievement_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") )
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id")
    private Campaign campaign;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reward_id")
    private Reward reward;
    private int numActionsRequired;
    private String actionType;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "achievements", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CustomerAction> customerActions = new ArrayList<CustomerAction>();
```

### EDIT 2

I am retrieving all of the achievements that belong to a specific campaign from this service endpoint method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/achievements", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Achievement> getAchievementsFromCampaign(@PathVariable int id) {
    List<Achievement> achievements = campaignService.getCampaignAchievements(id);
    return achievements;
}
```

### EDIT 3

It seems that if I use the JsonIgnore annotation on the reference to the parent entity (Campaign), then the numbers are replaced with the other JSON objects that I expect. I suppose that this is to prevent duplicate data from being shown in the JSON response.

So the numbers are actually the object IDs referring to the other Achievement objects that were already listed in the first nested Achievement JSON object.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're doing her. Perhaps some code sample for entity and your resource would help. But, generally, when you want to hide some attribute from showing up in Jackson response, you would use `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: @jFrenetic, I have edited the original post to provide a code sample of my entity and the resource that I'm fetching from it.

Comment: Don't see the resource code. But anyway, what are you trying to fetch? I see an achievement object in your response and some numbers. So, it's definitely not a campaign entity which has a list of Achievements, which would have been represented by array. I'd like to see what your service endpoint @GET/@POST (or whatever) method returns, if possible.

Comment: @jFrenetic, I am trying to fetch an Achievement collection that belongs to a Campaign one, given an ID for the latter. I've added the code for the service endpoint method that explicitly retrieves the Achievement arraylist from the Campaign. I'm not sure what you mean by "Don't see the resource code". The numbers at the end of the response are certainly not set in the Achievement class, but I am guessing that they are references to other objects? These numbers don't show up using JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference, but then I lose the two-way traversal that I get with JsonIdentityInfo.

Comment: Could it be that your campaignService returns some blank Achievement objects in the list? But in this case, I would expect something like `[ {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}...]`. The numbers in your sample response simply don't make sense. Might be some Hibernate/Spring related issue. I would try to map the result from Hibernate entity to some [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and then make the REST endpoint return it, just to be sure it's not some Hibernate-generated garbage.

Comment: @jFrenetic, I think what's happening is that if the JSON response grows too large, either Jackson or Hibernate is cutting off the response after one or two nested JSON objects and simply providing the IDs of the rest. This is probably due to my immature usage of EAGER type fetching...

Comment: I don't think it's size-related issue. I'm dealing with 500KB HTML strings in my JSON responses and it works fine for me, and your response looks quite complete. Sorry, can't be of any help here.

Comment: @jFrenetic, it seems that if I use the JsonIgnore annotation on the reference to the parent entity (Campaign), then the numbers are replaced with the other JSON objects that I expect. I suppose that this is to prevent duplicate data from being shown in the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer is to set the JSON identity reference always as true; see https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityReference.html.

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@NamedQuery(name = "Campaign.byId", query = "from Campaign where id=:id")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Campaign.class)
public class Campaign extends NamedEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private List<Achievement> achievements = new ArrayList<Achievement>();
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Achievement.byId", query = "from Achievement where id=:id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "EligibleAchievements.byCustomerActionId", query = "from Achievement a where :customerActionId not in (select ca.id from a.customerActions as ca) and :customerId not in (select c.id from a.customers as c)"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "CountedAchievements.byCustomerActionId", query = "from Achievement a where :id in (select ca.id from a.customerActions as ca)") })
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Achievement.class)
public class Achievement extends NamedEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Campaign campaign;
```

Resulting JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "dateCreated": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            9,
            33,
            23000000
        ],
        "dateModified": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            9,
            33,
            23000000
        ],
        "name": "First Check-In",
        "description": null,
        "qualifyingPeriodStartDate": [
            2015,
            9,
            1,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "customers": [],
        "campaign": 1,
        "reward": {
            "id": 1,
            "dateCreated": [
                2015,
                9,
                24,
                15,
                12,
                37,
                188000000
            ],
            "dateModified": [
                2015,
                9,
                24,
                15,
                12,
                37,
                188000000
            ],
            "name": "McFlurry",
            "customer": null,
            "rewardPointValue": 0,
            "chain": null,
            "achievements": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        },
        "numActionsRequired": 1,
        "actionType": "check-in",
        "customerActions": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "dateCreated": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            10,
            21,
            341000000
        ],
        "dateModified": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            10,
            21,
            341000000
        ],
        "name": "First Survey Completion",
        "description": null,
        "qualifyingPeriodStartDate": [
            2015,
            9,
            1,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "customers": [],
        "campaign": 1,
        "reward": 1,
        "numActionsRequired": 1,
        "actionType": "survey-completion",
        "customerActions": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "dateCreated": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            10,
            29,
            691000000
        ],
        "dateModified": [
            2015,
            9,
            23,
            18,
            10,
            29,
            691000000
        ],
        "name": "First Three Check-Ins",
        "description": null,
        "qualifyingPeriodStartDate": [
            2015,
            9,
            8,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "customers": [],
        "campaign": 2,
        "reward": 1,
        "numActionsRequired": 3,
        "actionType": "check-in",
        "customerActions": []
    }
]
```